# Express.js route and regex

Tags: javascript, regex, json, express, routes

I have an object like this :

```
geo: {
        description: 'Geolocalisation',
        properties: {
            latitude: {type: 'number'},
            longitude: {type: 'number'}
        }
    }
```

I want to create routes to retrive a nested object like :

> host/geo.schema or host/geo.json

to get the entire object

> host/geo/properties.schema or host/geo/properties.json

to get

```
properties: {
            latitude: {type: 'number'},
            longitude: {type: 'number'}
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with regex.

```
app.get('\/[a-zA-Z]+(\/[a-zA-Z]*)+(\.json|\.schema)', function (req, res) {
        var url = req.url.toLowerCase();

        var elements = url.split('/');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
var geo = {
    description: 'Geolocalisation',
    properties: {
        latitude: {type: 'number'},
        longitude: {type: 'number'}
    }
}

app.get('/host/geo.(schema|json)', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.status(200).json(geo);
});

app.get('/host/geo/properties.(schema|json)', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.status(200).json(geo.properties);
});
```

Comment: It does not work if I have : /host/geo/latitude.schema